# Truncated Double value(php)

Tags: php, mysql, database, truncated

i am working on how to update image with angular and send http request for the back office (PHP), so everything work fine , it delete the old file and insert the new one but the problem is this when come to insert the data into the database it show me an error.

```
$rest_json = file_get_contents("php://input");
$_POST = json_decode($rest_json, true);
/*recuperation et affichade de donnée*/
$id = (int)$_REQUEST['id'];
$nom = (string)$_REQUEST['nom'];
$image = $_POST['image'];
echo($id);
echo($nom);
$ok = false;

if (!empty($nom) && !empty($id) && !empty($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])) {
  /*selectionner et supprimer l'image ancien*/
    $query = "SELECT image_ser from etservice WHERE id_service='$id'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        $res = array();
        $res = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        unlink(($res[0]["image_ser"]));
    }
    /*preparer et inserer la nouvelle image et le nom*/
    $filetmp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    $filename = md5($tmp_name . time()) . "." . pathinfo($tmp_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    echo($filename);
    $filepath = "../assets/img/" . $filename;
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp, $filepath);
    $query = "UPDATE etservice set nom_service='$nom' AND image_ser='$filepath' WHERE id_service='$id'";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    if ($result === TRUE) {
        $res = "Inserted" . $nom. $id.$filepath;
        echo json_encode($res);
    } else {
        echo json_encode("Error" . $query . "<br>" . $db->error);
    }
}

break;
```

and this is the error when i try to insert a simple example to test

> ErrorUPDATE etservice set nom_service='trompita' AND
>   image_ser='../assets/img/d67a2bcf47122a855dab0dcfc5926c7d.jpg'
>   WHERE id_service='31'
> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value:
>   'trompita'""

and this is the database structure
[image: Database structure]
i ll be so grateful if any one help me

Comment: Can you please post the db table structure you are using to update ?

Comment: there it is in comment

Comment: Are you trying to insert or are you trying to update ? Because as per your comments you are trying to insert a value. UPDATE statements are used for updating the values. You'll have to use the INSERT statement to insert values.

Comment: i am trying to move the image for the needed folder and update it's url into the database that's it

Answer (score 0):

Just change the and statement into to query with "," so it become like so

```
$query1 = "UPDATE etservice set nom_service='$nom' , image_ser='$filepath' WHERE id_service='$id'";
```